# Not able to get the correct error message

Tags: webdriver

With the following code:

```html
<head>
  <body class="layout-two-column unibet uMyAccount">
    <div class="tooltip-container">
      <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip tooltip-error right-center" display: none;">
        <div class="tooltip-content gutter-3 icon icon-small icon-info">**Message 1**</div>
        <div class="tooltip-pointer"></div>
        <div class="tooltip-pointer-decoration"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="window">
      <div id="container" class="lobby-theme-3">
        <header id="header">
          <nav id="nav-main">
```

I need to get `Message 2` where the class name changes to `tooltip-content gutter-3 icon icon-small icon-error` with a java script. I need to get the error message which is `Message 2`.

Tried the below:

```
//body[contains(@class,'layout-two-column unibet uMyAccount')]//div[contains(@id,'tooltip')]//div[contains(@class,'tooltip-content')
```

If use the above xpath, and tried `String className = el.getAttribute("class");` its always fetching `tooltip-content gutter-3 icon icon-small icon-info` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
By tooltipSelector = By.xpath("//div[@id='tooltip']//div[contains(@class,'icon-error')]");
WebElement errorTooltip = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(tooltipSelector));
String className = errorTooltip.getAttribute("class");
```

Issues:

1. Your logic is wrong. You need to find `icon-error`, not `tooltip-content`. Since `tooltip-content` will always be there, WebDriver will find it before it's even changed. Unless you perform `sleep`.
2. You probably want to use WebDriverWait, because the element is created on the fly.
3. You don't need `body` in your xpath
4. `tooltip` is the id for the div, you don't need `div[contains(@id,'tooltip')]`
5. You may try css selectors `#tooltip .icon-error` in this case.

Comment: What should I do if i have to catch both the messages? Message 1 and Message 2. if you please let me know.

Comment: @user2340124: You can't catch both at the same time, because they are the same the element. What action triggers the change of the class name? Catch `Message 1` before the action and catch `Message 2` after that.

Comment: No, not needed to verify the same at once. But need to verify different conditions according to the occurrence of messages. Its the java script that triggers the change in class name.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

By tooltipSelector = By.cssSelector("#tooltip .icon-error");

WebElement errorTooltip = driver.findElement(tooltipSelector);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(tooltipSelector));

String className = errorTooltip.getAttribute("class");

Please Let me know is the above scripting works fine or not.